# PostConstruct member is null

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job the job has a member restApiConfiguration
this configuration is pre setup using @PostConstruct
I can see the code init() is running fine, but for some reason
restApiConfiguration    is null for other methods  like execute....
What can be the reason for that?

```
@Component
public class MyQuartzJob implements Job{

private restApiConfiguration =null;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    restApiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
}


@Transactional
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
       //restApiConfiguration  is null here
       restApiConfiguration.getWebServiceUrl();
}
```

Comment: is `someOtherMethod` somehow a part of Spring bean lifecycle? can it be triggered before the `@PostConstruct` method is called?

Comment: MyQuartzJob is a quartz job, and annotated with component, so i guess its part of part of Spring bean life-cycle, someOtherMethod is execute method, i will update the question

Comment: It's likely `someOtherMethod` is used on an instance you've created manually, not by means of Spring. So `init()` was triggered on the bean instance, `someOtherMethod()` on a plain instance outside the container...